# Element not found in Selenium test when div Element reloads after page load

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am creating an automation framework where I need to get the value from the element and match it with the value I have collected beforehand. Now , the issue is , div value is updated after page is loaded so even after adding implicit wait/fluent wait/Thread.sleep the code doesn't work.
But when I debug the code , the code works properly without doing any kind of changes.I am not sure what must be done regarding it.

Since I am a new user I cant add the image in this question but the initial 
"total : value " is " Total : 0 " and it takes some time to populate so it changes but since the page is loaded beforehand timeout is not working.

Kindly suggest something.

```
        String sID = oIPops.getLocator("<value from properties file>");

    /*
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,40);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(sID)));
    */

    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    String tValue = driver.findElement(By.id(sID)).getText();
    System.out.println(""+tValue);  // it will print Total : <populated value>

   // Extracting the number from the string to match with data I have beforehand
    char num = tValue.charAt(7);
    String character = "+" + num;
    Integer newNum = new Integer(character);
    if (value == newNum)
    {
        logger.info("Sum of Situations on Cluster "+title+ " matches with the total value from situation table");
    }
    else
    {
        logger.error("Sum of Situations on Cluster "+title+ " does not match with the total value from situation table");
    }
```

Comment: does the element with id=sID exist from the start in your html, or is the whole element injected later? if so, does it change only once? and lastly, is it initialized somehow in the static html?

Comment: Does the value change every time the page is loaded? I mean, could you explicitly wait for the value to change and only then get it?

Comment: The element exist from the start with default value 0 and the actual value is injected later.So it can change only once but that will depend till the page gets refreshed or the table from which the id value is populated gets refreshed. And I did try explicit wait but it doesnt work as i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy.  All you do is handle the element exception using the .ignoring method of the FluentWait class and then do a retry (within a finite loop) to re-find the element and try again.   It might be easier to do without using FluentWait and then just handle the exception the regular Java way.